# How can I use Excel VBA to output the exact same characters I get when type ALT+(number)?

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote a quick operation to generate a table to use as reference when using the <kbd>ALT</kbd> codes.  The output that I get does not match what is actually displayed when typing in the cell. For instance the output shows that <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> should be this `┘`, but if I actually type <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>, it shows this `♦`.

I am aware that I can use `CHRw()` to achieve any character, but I guess what I am looking for here is if there is a direct code that is the equivalent of holding <kbd>ALT</kbd> and pressing a number combination.

Here is the code that I used to generate the table:

```
Sub CHARACTER_TABLE()

    'DEFINE VARIABLES
    Dim CROW As Integer
    Dim CCOL As Integer
    Dim A As Integer

    CROW = 2
    CCOL = 1
    A = 1

    Do
        Cells(CROW, CCOL) = A
        Cells(CROW, (CCOL + 1)) = Chr(A)
        CROW = CROW + 1
        A = A + 1
        If CROW = 42 Then
            CROW = 2
            CCOL = CCOL + 3
        End If
        If A = 256 Then
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: I believe SendKeys "%" will press Alt

Comment: There isn't always a direct correlation between the Alt+ key combination and the ASCII character code.

Comment: I wrote an application where I used the Alt codes and typed the characters right into my code and it worked fine. Here is one of the lines: newString = VBA.Replace(newString, "PLB*", "µ*")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For codes without a leading zero, the character is translated from the system OEM code page:

```
ALT + 128  gives "Ç" with the code page 487 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437)
```

For codes with a leading zero, the character is translated from the system ANSI code page:

```
ALT + 0128  gives "€" with the code page 1251 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251)
```

To list the default OEM and ANSI characters in a sheet:

```
Private Declare Function MultiByteToWideChar Lib "kernel32" ( _
  ByVal codepage As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long, _
  ByRef lpMultiByteStr As Any, ByVal cchMultiByte As Long, _
  ByRef lpWideCharStr As Any, ByVal cchWideChar As Long) As Long

Function ChrEx(ByVal code As Integer, ByVal codepage As Long) As String
  Dim tgt(0 To 1) As Byte
  MultiByteToWideChar codepage, 4, code, 2, tgt(0), 2
  ChrEx = tgt
End Function

Sub DisplayCharSets()
  Dim r&, chars(1 To 255, 1 To 1) As String

  'List the system OEM code page in range A1
  chars(1, 1) = "OEM"
  For r = 2 To 255
    chars(r, 1) = ChrEx(r, 1) ' Default OEM code page = 1
  Next
  [A1:A255] = chars

  'List the system ANSI code page in range B1
  chars(1, 1) = "ANSI"
  For r = 2 To 255
    chars(r, 1) = ChrEx(r, 0) ' Default ANSI code page = 0
  Next
  [B1:B255] = chars

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for!